# Microsoft Outlook: Export list of currently opened PST files

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst

At my current workplace we are upgrading various users from XP to Windows 7.  Frequently the users have anywhere from 10 to 30 or so `.pst` files opened within their installation of Microsoft Outlook 2007.  These users are particularly helpless without these files.

I know how to view the list of currently opened PST files, and would like to know if there is an easy way to capture that information other than taking screenshots of the Options -> Data Files window.

Does `migwiz.exe` transfer this information?  Is that the only way?

Would there happen to be a tool that will let you capture and restore that information?

I don't want to export or move the actual `.pst`'s themselves (yes, some of them are on network locations, [very terrible, I know](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297019)), just reopen ones in a new installation of Outlook that used to be opened in a previous installation.

Comment: i've got a similar issue now, i need to go from '03 to '10. USMT won't migrate outlook, need to figure out how to export and import mounted pst's on the new machine automatically

Comment: Please don't create new tags when it's not necessary.

Comment: I have a vbscript that is capable of that, will that do ?

Comment: @Peter: Bring it on.

Comment: Will you still be using Outlook 2007 on the new computer? If different Outlook 32-bit or 64-bit? Going to Windows 7 32-bit or Windows 7 64-bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a vbscript that lists the PST's in the users profile

```
set objOutlook = createObject("Outlook.Application")
set objMAPI = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
for each PSTFolder In objMAPI.Folders
  pstPath = GetPath(PSTFolder.StoreID)
  if pstPath <> "" then
    wscript.echo PSTFolder.name & " : " & pstPath
  end if
next

function GetPath(input)
  for i = 1 To Len(input) Step 2
    strSubString = Mid(input,i,2)
    if Not strSubString = "00" Then
       strPath = strPath & ChrW("&H" & strSubString)
    end If
  next

  select Case True
  case InStr(strPath,":\") > 0
    GetPath = Mid(strPath,InStr(strPath,":\")-1)
  case InStr(strPath,"\\") > 0
    GetPath = Mid(strPath,InStr(strPath,"\\"))
  end Select
end Function
```

Comment: The issue with that is that that I've found is if a user has a shared mailbox attached to which they have no permissions. In that event, there's still an entry under the folders, but there's no StoreID associated and the script bombs out on the line:
    pstPath = GetPath(PSTFolder.StoreID)

Comment: That is indeed a very bad situation, my expereince with outlook 2010 is that it locks up and the pc comes to a crawl, best is to avoid such situation all together

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate an Outlook profile to another computer, it is a matter of [exporting and importing a registry tree](http://blog.shiraj.com/2012/04/how-to-export-outlook-profiles-from-one-computer-into-another/).

If on the off chance, you want to see what PST or OST are currently in use on a specific computer while Outlook is running, you can use the free handle tool by SysInternals:

c:>[handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) -p outlook.exe | grep "pst\|ost"

This looks at the process outlook.exe. grep will only pull the text from the out where it matches pst or ost.

PST is the local Outlook file.
OST is the Exchage cached file.

the grep I'm using is from cygwin.