# How can I keep all Outlook configurations when moving from 2007 to 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm about to move 400 employee from Office 2007 to Office 2010 and I would like to be able to "re-import" users pst files in outlook. Right now when I uninstall and reinstall office I lose all configurations, like all the PST files users have installed in there outlook.

So I would like to know if there is a way, maybe a registry key, I could backup before uninstalling and I could just re-add that key when the installation is finished?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you please [edit] your question to include what you have researched. With 400 users, I will assume this is a corporate domain running Exchange. Is that correct?

Comment: Try those two posts
http://superuser.com/questions/433878/microsoft-outlook-export-list-of-currently-opened-pst-files
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502664/which-registry-keys-determine-the-outlook-profile